# xmppPubSub didReceiveMessage delegate not getting call

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, subscribe

```
//setupStream
XMPPJID *serviceJID =[XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pubsub.%@",SERVICE]];
    _xmppPubSub = [[XMPPPubSub alloc]initWithServiceJID:serviceJID     dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [_xmppPubSub addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [_xmppPubSub activate:xmppStream];

//subscribe
 NSString *node=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pubsub_%@",[userDefault valueForKey:@"userJid"]] ;
[_xmppPubSub subscribeToNode:[node lowercaseString] withJID:xmppStream.myJID];

- (void)xmppPubSub:(XMPPPubSub *)sender didSubscribeToNode:(NSString *)node withResult:(XMPPIQ *)iq{
     NSLog(@"success!");
}

//this delegate not get call when published by server
-(void)xmppPubSub:(XMPPPubSub *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveMessage%@",message);
}
```

Comment: 1)node is creation is in server side.2)publishing data server side3)we are ios client side subscribe , the node is subscribed successfull but not geting packet from server

Comment: Multi-user chat